# SSL certificate error: self signed certificate in certificate chain in using Twilio on my Laravel Website

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, laravel-4, twilio

I am testing my codes on my localhost and I tried dtisgodsson/laravel4-twilio
to apply on my current website but I got this error

```
SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

right after I put this code inside my index.blade.php:

```
Twilio::to('119061539155')->message('This is so, damn, easy!');
```

What do I need to do to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

This error is caused by not having an up-to-date bundle of CA root certificates with your PHP installation. You need to download the latest CA root certificate bundle and update your php.ini to use this bundle. This [blog post](http://snippets.webaware.com.au/howto/stop-turning-off-curlopt_ssl_verifypeer-and-fix-your-php-config/) shows you how to accomplish both of those things.

Let me know if that gets you all fixed up!

Comment: For me, the above didn't work. In addition to the above, I had to manaully add the Thwate certificate to the cacert.pem. Got it from here - https://www.thawte.com/roots/thawte_Premium_Server_CA.pem  You can read the full story here (scroll to the bottom) - https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/issues/203

Comment: Since this is the accepted and most upvoted solution here, it shouldn't link off to another website that may get stale. This answer should be written in full so people can get what they need without going elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

If solution selected as answer to this question did not work, and you continue to have SSL authentication problems try this:

Change the setting twilio_use_certificate from false to true.

Find file OpenVBX/config/config.php and search for "twilio_use_certificate"

Then change FROM:

```
$config['twilio_use_certificate'] = false;
```

TO:

```
$config['twilio_use_certificate'] = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, do not disable certificate verifications - unless you are doing it when testing to see if it is the certificates that are causing your issue.  Either update the .ini file as mentioned elsewhere or point the httpclient to a version of the file you have downloaded.

Chances are you are using wamp or xamp or something and to avoid messing with .ini files every time you upgrade the PHP version you can do this:

```
use Twilio\Http\CurlClient;
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_CAINFO => "/path/to/cacert.pem"
);
$http = new CurlClient($options);

$client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token, $account_sid, 'US1', $http);
```

As mentioned elsewhere - download the new cacert file from https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html.